# How to create an user control containing collapsed text that is expandable on button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

Is it possible to create a WPF user control like this - a text region which is shown couple of lines initially and when user clicks a button it will open up the rest of the text ?

I have checked the expander class but dint find any properties with this behavior.

Comment: Show us what you have ended with? What is not working in your code. The answer to your question is, of course, **yes, it is possible**.

Comment: When I searched for expanding and collapsing I got redirected to expander and was reading about expander on what I have to do for this behavior. But dint find a property allows me to do a partial collapsing and expanding. If I am missing any property or other pre defined user control. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest example I can think of of such a behavior is the [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can modify its default Template to show whatever you want.

The default Template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx